# application loaded in iframe on facebook

Tags: iframe, facebook-graph-api

I have an app loaded in iframe on facebook.
But after allow and redirected to my facekooksite from facebook authorization i cant fetch the "code" from the querrystring from within my code (because loaded in an iframe on facebook)
How will i be able to fetch the "code" parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are following the server-side [authentication flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/). But since you are using Apps on Facebook, this flow will change since Facebook is sending a `signed_request` to your canvas iframe:

```
<?php 

     $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";

     $canvas_page = "YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE_URL";

     $auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);

     $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

     list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

     $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

     if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
            echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
     } else {
            echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"]);
     } 
 ?>
```

Obviously when you are on Facebook, the user is either connected to your app or not so if he/she is not connected then you redirect them to the authentication URL.